# Docker Volumes in AWS - Write to EBS, EFS, S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

How can I write docker containers in a Swarm to write data to any file system mount such as EBS, EFS, or even read data from S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Got EFS, EBS, S3 Plugins with AWS Policy Working

Full answer details at https://github.com/codedellemc/rexray/issues/820#issuecomment-323624765.

- I used RexRay Docker Volume plugin for EBS, EFS, and S3 support

  - The volume allows you to automatically load one of those as a file-system mount inside the container without using ANY AWS API. That is, transparently to the container!!!

Here is the example

```
docker service create --replicas 10 
    --name echo-to-efs 
    --mount type=volume,source=echo_data,target=/test,volume-driver=rexray/efs 
    alpine /bin/sh -c 'echo "writing from $HOSTNAME" >> \
                 /test/echo.log ; cat /test/echo.log ; sleep 30'
iy4rzd4imq776abjlqdqf8l10
```

`EFS MOUNTS`
[image]

`EBS MOUNTS`
[image]

### Install Volume Plugin

- Installation process described at https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/docker-plugins/#amazon

Repeat for each of them, using their docker command-line arguments...

`[root@ip-10-zz-yy-xx ec2-user]# sudo docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions rexray/s3fs
latest: Pulling from rexray/s3fs
5a6437c91cc6: Download complete
Digest: sha256:6ba105974d5298ff49def3c83e5547d41e573e0a3cb8604f1dcb1a0f90ee070b
Status: Downloaded newer image for rexray/s3fs:latest
Installed plugin rexray/s3fs`

### Docker Plugin ls

- After setting up the UserData to install the 3 plugins , everything works properly!

`[ec2-user@ip-10-82-48-59 ~]$ docker plugin ls
ID                  NAME                 DESCRIPTION                                     ENABLED
0eb15d4a9594        rexray/s3fs:latest   REX-Ray FUSE Driver for Amazon Simple Stor...   true
6bae636cb377        rexray/ebs:latest    REX-Ray for Amazon EBS                          true
9e231d9177c2        rexray/efs:latest    REX-Ray for Amazon EFS                          true`

### Docker Containers automatically creating/mounting Volumes

As a rule of thumb, I learned the following:

- EFS = Concurrent Writes (x replicas scenarios)
- EBS = Single Writes (1 replicate scenarios)

So, the example below shows the following:

- Create 10 Docker Containers concurrently writing to the same file

`Last login: Mon Aug 21 00:34:46 2017 from 10.82.49.230
[ec2-user@ip-10-zz-yy-xx ~]$ docker service create --replicas 10 
         --name echo-to-efs

         --mount type=volume,source=echo_data,target=/test,volume-driver=rexray/efs 
        alpine /bin/sh -c 'echo "writing from $HOSTNAME" >> /test/echo.log ; cat /test/echo.log ; sleep 30'
iy4rzd4imq776abjlqdqf8l10`

- The `docker ps` shows some of them writing and failures

  - If someone can explain why some failures in the case please let me know...
  - I have `REXRAY_PREEMPT=true` so, not sure if that's not related

`[ec2-user@ip-10-82-48-59 ~]$ docker service ps echo-to-efs
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                           DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                 ERROR                              PORTS
8c8lxqcoc3n5        echo-to-efs.1       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal    Running             Running 8 seconds ago
23meciw5cvad        echo-to-efs.2       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-49-52.vpc.internal    Running             Running 2 seconds ago
si7lg30kb13b         \_ echo-to-efs.2   alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-93.vpc.internal    Shutdown            Failed about a minute ago     "starting container failed: er…"
rmj163xu97ai        echo-to-efs.3       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal    Running             Running 7 seconds ago
5jtao2yu5udt        echo-to-efs.4       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-95.vpc.internal    Running             Running 8 seconds ago
wot9hd5nbjsz        echo-to-efs.5       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-49-71.vpc.internal    Running             Running 7 seconds ago
hcbbgfiuga9c        echo-to-efs.6       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-140.vpc.internal   Running             Starting 49 seconds ago
wrnnrsm16usr         \_ echo-to-efs.6   alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-25.vpc.internal    Shutdown            Rejected 58 seconds ago       "create echo_data: VolumeDrive…"
w3v4x0pf9uri         \_ echo-to-efs.6   alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-37.vpc.internal    Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "create echo_data: VolumeDrive…"
okgda40hb4hy         \_ echo-to-efs.6   alpine:latest       ip-10-82-49-107.vpc.internal   Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "create echo_data: VolumeDrive…"
bzoafno0gb4d        echo-to-efs.7       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal    Running             Running 7 seconds ago
rk7uebz4cdql        echo-to-efs.8       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-49-111.vpc.internal   Running             Running 6 seconds ago
hy1rfid4zitl        echo-to-efs.9       alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-162.vpc.internal   Running             Running 7 seconds ago
k5lmmmu44yh3        echo-to-efs.10      alpine:latest       ip-10-82-48-187.vpc.internal   Running             Running 8 seconds ago`

- Now we can verify if the file is being written...

`[ec2-user@ip-10-82-48-59 ~]$ docker service logs echo-to-efs
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from 3da21bc313f7
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from 3da21bc313f7
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from 334b26ce3747
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from 3da21bc313f7
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from 334b26ce3747
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from 334b26ce3747
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from fcefd6eb5035
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from 84ffd56fdcfa
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from b7ecbd01debe
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from e5ef2a2821a2
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from 5179f81f04f9
echo-to-efs.1.8c8lxqcoc3n5@ip-10-82-48-59.vpc.internal     | writing from 5e859dce0c2f
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from fcefd6eb5035
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from fcefd6eb5035
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from 84ffd56fdcfa
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from b7ecbd01debe
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from 84ffd56fdcfa
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from b7ecbd01debe
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from e5ef2a2821a2
echo-to-efs.4.5jtao2yu5udt@ip-10-82-48-95.vpc.internal     | writing from 3da21bc313f7
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from 5179f81f04f9
echo-to-efs.7.bzoafno0gb4d@ip-10-82-48-74.vpc.internal     | writing from e5ef2a2821a2
echo-to-efs.3.rmj163xu97ai@ip-10-82-48-96.vpc.internal     | writing from 5e859dce0c2f
...
...`

- Now see the current value in the file.

  - The command here will mount the volume and at the same and then read the file from EFS mount.
  - It does take a long while until the container prepares the mount... Like 2min... Not sure if that's expected.

`[ec2-user@ip-10-82-48-59 ~]$ docker run -ti --volume-driver=rexray/efs -v echo_data:/test alpine cat /test/echo.log
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:1072e499f3f655a032e88542330cf75b02e7bdf673278f701d7ba61629ee3ebe
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
writing from 3da21bc313f7
writing from 334b26ce3747
writing from fcefd6eb5035
writing from 84ffd56fdcfa
writing from b7ecbd01debe
writing from e5ef2a2821a2
writing from 5179f81f04f9
writing from 5e859dce0c2f
writing from af94a5a29b4a
writing from a3f860caaf03
writing from b7b3d30d2f8e
writing from cf65a52760c0
writing from a551b529e599
writing from 0533784ce9e5
writing from d78f781baa4d
writing from 06b84229ec32
writing from 4e3974cfb8a9
writing from 007cd66062e7
writing from 665f76589ae2
writing from 68b04985559a
writing from 9a2e19e110fb
writing from 1ed7903abf86
writing from 763c7eea52fb
writing from 529c7fff9c71
writing from 7172d5fb56d9
writing from c33294ce8d9d
writing from b95a5b5f1bc1
writing from ff269d8a78ba
writing from b1299af12f30
writing from 4f970a6e234d
writing from a4a1f331b3c9
writing from bb3915d9d242
writing from 0fbafba12a0c
writing from 017f70a769da
writing from 8d657b23571f
writing from 570e2fa76e16
writing from 45a92f3d19b4
writing from 3b02cb3675e4
writing from e2d49358df6f`

### Docker Volumes Status

- Docker volumes now maps all the Mounts with the Plugins

  - This is a major win for me!

`[ec2-user@ip-10-82-48-59 ~]$ docker volume ls
DRIVER               VOLUME NAME
rexray/s3fs:latest   7820-3357-5600-us-west-2
rexray/s3fs:latest   cf-templates-8hmsxuf2muaa-us-west-2
rexray/efs:latest    echo_data
rexray/s3fs:latest   marcello-12345
rexray/s3fs:latest   marcello-testing-bucket-1
rexray/s3fs:latest   marcello-testing-bucket-2
rexray/s3fs:latest   new-config-publisher
rexray/s3fs:latest   publisher.intuit-caas
rexray/s3fs:latest   publisher.intuit-caas-new-update
rexray/ebs:latest    quay-registry-configs
rexray/ebs:latest    quay-registry-images-datastore
rexray/ebs:latest    quay-registry-mysql-datastore
rexray/ebs:latest    registry_configs
rexray/ebs:latest    registry_mysql-data
rexray/s3fs:latest   swarmbucket-vpc-155e5072`

Comment: How do you and where do you  set AWS access and secret keys?

Comment: @Zahid I'm afraid it was set in the env... I don't recall, but maybe refer to the latest docs... I'm not sure if this is still valid...